# C reading input from a file with scientific notation into 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I am given a list of 24 scientific numbers in 1 column as txt file (use %le format).

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>



    void main()
    {
      int i;
      int j;

    /*matrix*/

    double** mat=malloc(24*sizeof(double*)); 
    for(i=0;i<24;++i)
    mat[i]=malloc(1*sizeof(double));


        FILE *file;
        file=fopen("input.txt", "r");


        if ((file = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL)
      {
         printf("Error! opening file");
         // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);         
      }

     else

   for(i = 0; i < 24; i++)
 {
  for(j = 0; j < 1; j++) 
  {

   if (!fscanf(file, "%le", &mat[i][j])) 
       break;

    printf("%le\n",mat[i][j]);
  } 


 }
  fclose(file);
 }
```

Now i want to put this 1d array of 24 elements into a 4 by 6 matrix A.

how do i do that?

i have tried doing=>

```
  for(m=1;m<=4;m++)
  {
    for(n=1;n<=6;n++)
        {
            mat[k][1]=A[i][j];

            k++;
        }   

  }

        printf("%lf \n",A[i][j]);
```

But this does nothing.I am new to C so any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

The program is too long for a simple task like read and write in a matrix i know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(m=1;m<=4;m++)
{
  for(n=1;n<=6;n++)
  {
    mat[k][1]=A[i][j];
    k++;
  }
}
```

Your loop indices are `m` and `n`, but you're using `i` and `j` as your subscripts - `i` and `j` never get initialized or updated in the loop.

The bigger problem is that your are assigning the value of `A[i][j]` to `mat[k][1]`, rather than the other way around.

But this still has a problem - remember that in C, an N-element array is indexed from 0 to N-1.  If `A` is a 4x6 array and `mat` is a 24x1 array (more on that later), then your loop should be written

```
for ( m = 0; m < 4; m++ )
{
  for ( n = 0; n < 6; n++ )
  {
    A[m][n] = mat[k++][0];
  }
}
```

The first element is at index 0, the second is at index 1, etc.

Regarding `mat`...

It's not clear why you need to allocate `mat` dynamically if you know it's going to store 24 values.  It's also not clear why it needs to be a 24x1 array.  Just declare it as a 24-element array of `double`:

```
double mat[24];
...
for ( i = 0; i < 24; i++ )
{
  if ( scanf( file, "%le", &mat[i] ) != 1 )
    // handle read error
}
...
for ( k = 0, i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
  for ( j = 0; j < 6; j++ )
    A[i][j] = mat[k++];
```

Finally, `void main()` should be `int main( void )`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't increase i,j indexes in your loop and you should put printf inside the second loop.

Try this

```
k=0;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 for(j=0;j<6;j++)
 {
  A[i][j] = *(mat[k++]);
  printf("%f\n",A[i][j]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(m=1;m<=4;m++) //wrong counters
{
    for(n=1;n<=6;n++)
    {
        mat[k][1]=A[i][j]; //does not assign anything
        k++;
    }   
}
printf("%lf \n",A[i][j]); //not in loop
```

You should start counting from 0 in the for loop, since arrays are indexed from 0. And make sure you are using the right symbols, and have declared k as an int and initialized it, ie `int k = 0;`.

The thing you want to assign a value to must be on the left, and what is being assigned must be on the right.

Lastly, your print statement is not in the loop.

Here is an example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
        A[i][j] = mat[k][0];
        k++;
        printf("%lf \n",A[i][j]);
    }
}
```